# What do exclamation marks instead of number output in fortran mean?

Tags: fortran, output

I have legacy fortran code in which I am printing some numbers to a file, without a format statement. Now some of this output looks like this:

```
 ah !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! afn !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 ah !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! afn +*************************
 ah !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! afn +*************************
 ah !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! afn !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 ah !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! afn   6.31304569736211807
```

The corresponding code is:

```
write(6,*) 'ah', ah(nzaehl),'afn',afn(nzaehl)
```

The `ah` and `afn` are just arrays that should contain real numbers. This output is for debugging purposes to find out what these arrays really look like. As it is, as long as I don't know what the exclamation marks mean, I don't really know where it goes wrong.

The lines that contain asteriscs are numbers that are too big, if I understand correctly, but what do the exclamation marks mean? I can't find anything on google for some reason, so I would really appreciate an explanation.

The compiler used is `f90`. At least that's what is called in the makefile.

Comment: Would be helpful to know which numbers you are trying to print, and which compiler you are using.

Comment: Probably debugging lines accidentally left in, possibly by somebody with the initials afn or ah

Comment: @IanBush Yes, debugging lines is correct, but they are there because I'm trying to debug, so not accidentally.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark No, that's all there is in the makefile. It might well be that the compiler is somehow specific to the machine it's running on, or that this is a shell shortcut, I just don't know how to find out.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark `f90` has a `man` entry, which says "f90 invokes Optimizing FORTRAN90 Compiler OFORT90.". I don't know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hitachi? What kind of computer and OS is that?

Comment: @VladimirF it's what's commonly known as a supercomputer.

Comment: @fifaltra There are many things which people call supercomputer and most of them are different. (Most are just x86 clusters, some maybe NEC or whatever. Hitachi's are very rare today.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the culprit, these weird exclamation marks are apparently the result of dividing 0 by 0, i.e. NaN. Why it doesn't just say "NaN" is a mystery to me.

I really don't know how many people are using the same compiler, judging from the comments not many, but I thought I'd put this information out there for future reference.